# Keyboard keycap protection film or laquer to stop letters rubbing off

Tags: keyboard

Any ideas on how to stop the lettering on a new keyboard from rubbing off? I am about to replace my Microsoft ergonomic 4000 keyboard which suffers from this and I am thinking of ways to stop the problem without affecting my typing too much.

Current thoughts are to:

1. Use a layer of clear nail varnish on the keytops?
2. Find some type of self adhesive plastic film?

Does anyone have preferably stories on solutions they have tried, but ideas are welcome too. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: heh, I'd say go for a keyboard with standard, replacable caps, but I'm a mechanical keyboard nut. Or maybe a keyboard with no lettering at all.

Comment: a touch typing course?    :-)

Comment: Hi @JourneymanGeek, I am restricted by having to have an ergonomic keyboard and knowing the the 4000 works for me, (not all do). Unfortunately #mcalex I cannot touch type (although I am being forced to type from memeory of some key positions as several keys show only a faint grey outline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the same keyboard - there's a few options - silicone covers exist for that specific model apparently so it might be worth considering - look for Part# 878E122.

For a more ghetto solution, [cnet](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57581662-263/protect-your-keyboards-keys-from-fading-into-oblivion/) seems to think covering the keys in packing tape may help. If you do decide to use nail varnish, I'd suggest the sensible thing and testing it on a less visible part - lots of keys are made of ABS, and since nail varnish is acetone soluble in many cases, it may react badly.

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek. I think the silicone gel cover would affect my typing too much, but I could try the tape when I first see my new keyboard keys start fading. Are their other types of varnish that are more plastic friendly?

Comment: I'd probably test it first to be sure, its a bit like using something to clean them

Answer (score 1):

I re-painted the letters on my keyboard using a small bottle of appliance touch-up paint. First, I clean the keys with plain rubbing alcohol and let them dry. To apply the paint, I use the pointed end of a round toothpick as this makes a nice, fine line.  The best time for me to do this is right before bedtime so the paint can dry overnight. However, over time, the paint will eventually chip off and this will have to be done again but for me, it usually holds up for a few months. Fortunately, a bottle of appliance touch-up paint will last for a very, very long time if this is all you use it for.  If you want to, you can make the letters extra large so you can see them even better.
Tip:  Practice painting with a toothpick first before you try it on the keys. It's not hard to do once you get the hang of it especially if you make the letters large.